# php oop jquery ajax : Undefined index

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

how to solve the undefined index error? see below for my code

on Products Class

```
public function add(){
    var_dump($_POST);
    $pname = $_POST['pname'];
    echo $pname;
}
```

ajax code:

```
$('#productsform').on('submit', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var data = $('#productsform').serialize();
    $.ajax({ 
      url:'action.php',
      data: {'action': 'add', 'data': data},
      type: 'post',
      success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
      }
    });
});
```

here is action.php

```
include_once('classes/Products.php');

$product = new Products();

if(isset($_POST['action'])){
    if($_POST['action'] == 'add'){
        $product->add();
        exit();
    }
}
```

now, the output in console log:

```
array(2) {
  ["action"]=>
  string(3) "add"
  ["data"]=>
  string(29) "pname=asdadsad&pprice=&pdesc="
}
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: pname in <b>D:\xampp\htdocs\prince2\classes\Products.php</b> on line <b>25</b><br />
```

i already type "asdadsad" as input for named pname..

pls help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change like this:

```
$('#productsform').on('submit', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var data = $('#productsform').serialize(); // pass action in hidden field 
    $.ajax({ 
      url:'action.php',
      data: data,
      type: 'post',
      success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
      }
    });
});
```

Comment: thank you it works, the undefined index for all textboxes are gone .. but yet the undefined index for select option are still display on console log.

my form consists of 3 texbox 2 selection option and 1 input type file.

Comment: That means you need to declare selection option variable in code

Comment: hi ahmed, i thought the .serialize() will get all the value of the tags in a form that has a name attribute, so i wonder that the .serialize() cant get the select option tag

Comment: You can add that data as..  $('#productsform').serialize() + "&moredata=" + morevalue